# Select get data attribute value and embed as select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am new to Vuejs. Requirement here, from backend they will configure time slot values into data-times attributes in array format.

I need to extract and update this time slot based on location selected.

If Location 1 is selected, option `data-times - 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 10:30 AM - 11:30 AM` have to embed as option value into select `name=time`.

Also, if query parameter `?l=loc1` exists.. we need to preselect select `name=location` and select `name=time` need to change timeslot accordingly.

Not sure how to bring this logic via Vuejs. Is there any possible way to bring this expected behaviour?

```html
<select name="location" class="chosen-select select-picker select-picker-link" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select location</option>
    <option value="loc1" data-times="['10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 10:30 AM - 11:30 AM']">Location 1</option>
    <option value="loc2" data-times="['11:00 AM - 12:00 PM, 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM']">Location 2</option>
    <option value="loc3" data-times="['10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 10:30 AM - 11:30 AM, 11:30 AM - 12:30 PM']">Location 3</option>
</select>


<select name="time" class="chosen-select select-picker select-picker-link" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a timeslot</option>
    <option value="10:00 AM - 11:00 AM">10:00 AM - 11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="10:30 AM - 11:30 AM">10:30 AM - 11:30 AM</option>
    <option value="11:00 AM - 12:00 PM">11:00 AM - 12:00 PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use `@change="method"` on select1 then explode the result and pass result to select2..

Comment: @Jazuly Thanks for your comment. But i am not sure how to use this method!! thats why posted my query to learn and understand the syntax for these kind of requirements.

Comment: Can the value in `data-times` be modified? Right now it's not in a format that is easily parseable. This might be easier: `data-times="10:00 AM - 11:00 AM,10:30 AM - 11:30 AM`, then it's a matter of splitting it by `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are allowed to make minor adjustments to the value injected into the `data-times` attribute (needed to make parsing easier), you can simply use `v-model` and then set up a watcher for the data property used in the `v-model` binding of the location dropdown.

The check the query string, it is a matter of checking `window.location.search` and then parsing it using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get). If the value is truthy, then we can use it to set the value in `v-model`. Since everything is reactive, any changes/mutations to the `v-model` value will update the second select dropdown.

Check out the proof-of-concept below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      location: '',
      time: '',
      times: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // Parse `?l=<LOCATION>` during app mounted hook
    // For testing, you can try:
    // const query = new URLSearchParams('?l=loc3');
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (query.get('l')) {
      this.location = query.get('l');
    }
  },
  watch: {
    location: {
      immediate: true,
      handler: async function() {
      
        // Wait for DOM to update before attempting to access DOM elements
        await this.$nextTick();
        
        // Reset selection in time
        this.time = '';

        // Re-populated array of available times
        this.times = this.$refs.locationEl.selectedOptions[0].dataset.times.split(',');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select name="location" v-model="location" ref="locationEl">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select location</option>
    <option value="loc1" data-times="10:00 AM - 11:00 AM,10:30 AM - 11:30 AM">Location 1</option>
    <option value="loc2" data-times="11:00 AM - 12:00 PM,12:00 PM - 1:00 PM">Location 2</option>
    <option value="loc3" data-times="10:00 AM - 11:00 AM,10:30 AM - 11:30 AM, 11:30 AM - 12:30 PM">Location 3</option>
  </select>


  <select name="time" v-model="time">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a timeslot</option>
    <option v-for="(time, i) in times" v-bind:key="i" v-bind:value="time">{{ time }}</option>
  </select>

  <ul>
    <li><strong>Location:</strong> {{ location }}</li>
    <li><strong>Time:</strong> {{ time }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```